# Create New Attribute Group in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, php, magento-enterprise, database

In Magento products attributes are assigned in Groups under an attribute set. I am trying to create a new Attribute Group like `General`, `Price`.

- I want assigned the new product attribute to that new attribute group not to the "General"

[image]

My finding till now is :

- Attribute Groups are stored in `eav_attribute_group` table

[image]

How it can be achieved programmatically?
Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
$sets = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->getResourceCollection()
    ->addFilter('entity_type_id', $entityTypeId);

foreach ($sets as $set){
    //create attribute group instance
    $modelGroup = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group');
    //set the group name
    $modelGroup->setAttributeGroupName('Some group name here')
    //link to the current set
    ->setAttributeSetId($set->getId())
    //set the order in the set
    ->setSortOrder(15);
    $modelGroup->save();
}
```

check here for more: [Create and add attribute group with attributes to all attribute sets](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/create-and-add-attribute-group-with-attributes-to-all-attribute-sets)

Comment: Thanks for reply Anil. I checked the link provided by you. But i don't want to add this group to all the attribute set.

Comment: If possible please add some line of description also. that will be really helpful to understand the code. Thanks

Comment: `->setAttributeSetId($set->getId())` pass ID of an attribute set you want here and remove `foreach` loop

Comment: is this worked ?